# Enable schemaCreationSupport in spring-boot-starter-data-solr

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-boot, spring-data-solr

I use spring-boot-starter-data-solr and would like to make use of the schmea cration support of Spring Data Solr, as stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr#automatic-schema-population):

> Automatic schema population will inspect your domain types whenever the applications context is refreshed and populate new fields to your index based on the properties configuration. This requires solr to run in Schemaless Mode.

However, I am not able to achieve this. As far as I can see, the Spring Boot starter does not enable the *schemaCreationSupport* flag on the *@EnableSolrRepositories* annotation. So what I tried is the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSolrRepositories(schemaCreationSupport = true)
public class MyApplication {
  @Bean
  public SolrOperations solrTemplate(SolrClient solr) {
    return new SolrTemplate(solr);
  }
}
```

But looking in Wireshark I cannot see any calls to the Solr Schema API when saving new entities through the repository.

Is this intended to work, or what am I missing? I am using Solr 6.2.0 with Spring Boot 1.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem. After some debugging, I've found the root cause why the schema creation (or update) is not happening at all:

By using the `@EnableSolrRepositories` annotation, an Spring extension will add a factory-bean to the context that creates the `SolrTemplate` that is used in the repositories. This template initialises a `SolrPersistentEntitySchemaCreator`, which **should do the creation/update**.

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() {

  if (this.mappingContext == null) {
    this.mappingContext = new SimpleSolrMappingContext(
      new SolrPersistentEntitySchemaCreator(this.solrClientFactory)
       .enable(this.schemaCreationFeatures));
  }

  // ...
}
```

Problem is that the flag `schemaCreationFeatures` (which enables the creator) is set **after the factory calls** the `afterPropertiesSet()`, so it's impossible for the creator to do it's work.

I'll create an issue in the spring-data-solr issue tracker. Don't see any workaround right now, other either having a custom fork/build of spring-data or extend a bunch of spring-classes and trying to get the flag set before by using (but doubt of this can be done).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the analysis.